# No response from XML using cURL

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

I am using a simple cURL statement to parse XML on my site. When the API is up and working it works fine, however as soon as the API does down for any reason the entire site crashes.

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/webservicexample';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($data);
```

Is there a conditional I can put around the url so that it only carries out the cURL script if there's a positive response from the API? I tried the following but it didn't work because it never got a server response to give any headers:

```
$url_headers = @get_headers($url);
if($url_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {

    // do script
}
```

Any help/advice much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@` before `get_headers()` to show any errors?

Comment: Look into error logs to see which error is crashing the script.

Comment: @Titanium - I tried this but it still didn't work

Comment: @Ranty - the error is on the API side, I'll see if the API provider has any reasons for it timing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the return value of `curl_exec()`:

```
if (false === ($data = curl_exec($ch))) {
    die("Eek! Curl error! " . curl_error($ch));
}
```

And check the response headers too:

```
if (200 !== (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
    die("Oh dear, no 200 OK?!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, my answer below is working for me, but yours looks like it should work too.

Comment: @AdamMoss No problem, my answer only solved the part of knowing when the request fails (for whatever reason); it didn't take into account that a timeout should be set to avoid having to wait 60 seconds before  it gives up.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to get it working by setting a timeout time with CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and then put a conditional around it using curl_errno().

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!curl_errno($ch))
    {
        curl_close($ch); 
        $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($data);
        return $xml;
    }
```